# Movie with a Surprise Alien/Monster in a Mountain at the end

Tags: identify-this-movie

It was a horror/monster movie (or, with slim possibility, a TV show, but I'm fairly certain it was a movie). It was about little monsters or aliens (unsure) that attacked people and ate them. I believe they were essentially elongated heads with lots of teeth, about the size and shape of a football. I don't remember how or why they showed up, or even how they were ultimately defeated. I'm pretty sure it was live-action.

The one thing I do remember distinctly is that, at the end of the movie, as the camera pans up after the ordeal has been settled and everyone thinks its over, a mountain in the distance stands up and opens its mouth, revealing itself to be a massive version of the smaller creatures. That's the only distinct piece I have to go on.

The exact details from the middle, I'm not sure. But the "mountain is actually a monster/alien" ending is the firm detail in my mind. I was very young, so it's all I remember clearly.

I saw it at home in the **late 80s or early 90s** in the United States, but I don't know how new it was at that time. It was **color**, and I don't know if it was a rented movie on VHS or shown on TV, but I would guess it was on TV.

I'm fairly certain it is **not** the movie(s) "Critters" about the little hairball monsters, although if I'm wrong (and that ending shows up in one of those films), that's okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Deadly Spawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deadly_Spawn), (1983), aka **Return of the Alien's Deadly Spawn**.

> That night, a lone patrolman stands guard outside the house. His
>   contact on the CB radio is confident that the spawn has been wiped
>   out, but then the patrolman hears a low rumbling, and **sees the hill by
>   the house lift up, revealing that it sits atop the mouth of a colossal
>   spawn**.

Comment: This seems incredibly likely, given the description of the ending. The nature of the creatures doesn't match what I remember, but that could be my faulty recollection. Before I accept as the answer, I want to see if it's possible to find the ending (or the whole movie) somewhere, but this will likely be marked as correct either way.

Comment: Well, I can't seem to find anywhere to see the movie, but based on the description that's got to be it. Thanks for the find! I'll keep looking, but I can't imagine a lot of movies ended that way, so here you go! Now I just need to figure out why my parents had me watching that (and others) when I was in Kindergarten...

Comment: Just to fully credit you: I found the movie and was able to watch the ending, and that was definitely it! Very impressive find, given that I had several of the details wrong!